# How to pass the li tag id via AJAX when clicking the li item?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to pass id value to show city function on click of li tag values any any relevant method is accepted

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
  function showCity(str) {
    if (str == "") {
      document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = "";
      return;
    } else {
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }

      xmlhttp.open("GET", "city.php?q=" + str, true);
      xmlhttp.send();

    }
  } 
</script>


<div id="menu">
  <ol id="test">

    <?php $stat=m ysql_query( "select * from `tms_state`"); while (($st=m ysql_fetch_array($stat))) { ?>

    <li onclick="showCity('this.value')">
      <?php echo "<option value='" . $st[ 'id'] . "'>" . $st[ 'name'] . "</option>";?>
    </li>

    <?php } ?>

  </ol>

</div>
```

I want to pass id value to show city function on click of li tag values.

Comment: please help me what to do its been long time i am working on it

Comment: What exactly you're looking for ? please let me know. What i understood once click on the <li> tag you need <li> text ?

Comment: i am using li item value which is coming from database i want when i click that item its id value should come in to showcity(this.value) so that it can be assigned to ajax argument str.right now it is taking this.value as string in place of li item tag value id

Comment: no i want id value on click to showcity() function

Comment: please check in firebug, whether the AJAX call is being done. I dont think this function <li onclick="showCity('this.value')"> will work. because li does nt have a value attribute here

Comment: Bhadra it just passing this.value in place of id i checked in firebug this is the problem

Comment: thanx bhadra it works like charm.thank you.it solave my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="menu">
    <ol id="test">

    <?php 
       $stat=m ysql_query( "select * from `tms_state`");
       while (($st=m ysql_fetch_array($stat))) { ?>

      <li onclick="showCity('<?php echo $st[ 'id'] ?>')">
          <?php echo "$st[ 'id']";?>
       </li>

    <?php } ?>

     </ol>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this a lot easier with jQuery -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test li').click(function () {
        var str = $(this).val();

        $.ajax(
            {
                url: "city.php?q=" + str,
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#city").html(result);
                }
            });
      });
 });
```